# LDAPS OpenLDAP Outlook 365

Tags: ssl, openldap

When I try to connect to my openLDAP service (on Ubuntu 18.04), using SSL from Outlook 365 I get a connection error. When I try to connect with LdapAdmin Client I *can* connect, using over SSL too, but I get a warning for an "untrusted certificate".

Testing this with `OpenSSL -showcert` on Port 636, I get the following output (certificate data deleted). My chain looks fine (for me).

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
CONNECTED(00000144)
depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root CA
verify error:num=19:self signed certificate in certificate chain
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:C = DE, ST = Example, L = Example, O = Example, CN = ldap.Example.de
   i:C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, CN = DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIHSDCCBjCgAwIBAgIQDl1qcjCl3eK6YxOqO4W98zANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBN
...
EoMrMT5ArQyW5wdS5S8k1FaQ5XtHwWW3L6pAtcDW9i3/rUQRVrqqmkIwtBY=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, CN = DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
   i:C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIElDCCA3ygAwIBAgIQAf2j627KdciIQ4tyS8+8kTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBh
...
j6tJLp07kzQoH3jOlOrHvdPJbRzeXDLz
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 2 s:C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root CA
   i:C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global Root CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDrzCCApegAwIBAgIQCDvgVpBCRrGhdWrJWZHHSjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBh
...
CAUw7C29C79Fv1C5qfPrmAESrciIxpg0X40KPMbp1ZWVbd4=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
Server certificate
subject=C = DE, ST = Example, L = Example, O = Example, CN = ldap.Example.de
 issuer=C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, CN = DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA256
Peer signature type: RSA
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 4762 bytes and written 447 bytes
Verification error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Server public key is 4096 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Session-ID: 10A01A15EF18ADC670E8A67448B1B1CB0C34E444523F862331CCC4BBAAD7D05C
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: 06A3BB95671AF2277F9DDB9FD0E3E2076E79B9583B8D04159A1ABFF8B59C9DB75DDF80BA14A0F47D561E60074300D9F9
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1559732770
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
    Extended master secret: yes
---
```

Comment: use the formatting tools to make your post readable.

Comment: also furthermore: You have a hint there right in the output: "Verification error: self signed certificate in certificate chain"

Comment: The point is I don't have one... the first certificate is my company's certificate signed by DigiCert. After that there is DigiCert Intermediate followed by DigiCert root....

Answer (score 1):

The server certificate in your chain is a self-signed one, with a CN containig 'example.de', which looks like an example (as long as you aren't managing ldap.Example.de).

```
s:C = DE, ST = Example, L = Example, O = Example, CN = ldap.Example.de
```

Just remove it and use a proper issued one (and don't forget to attach the complete certificate chain).

Comment: thanks for your answer.  I Just switched my customer's name to "Example".

The first certificate is my customer's certificate signed by DigiCert. After that there is DigiCert Intermediate followed by DigiCert root....

Comment: Ah, okay, sorry, that wasn't obvious (to me). Either way, it's self signed.